# My AVD Emulator won't start

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm so desperate.

I'm running eclipse Juno, the lastest version.

I had some problems with the program, so I re-installed eclipse.
And now the AVD Emulator won't run my project or start itself.

The AVD Manager has no problem, only the emulator is the only thing that's not working.

In the Console Box, it says this:

Failed to allocate memory: 8
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Well... has the problem caused by me?
I've got no idea.

Can give you guys more information about my errors, I'm open.

I can't find any other answers about this in stackoverflow.
I've waited about 20 minutes or so after pressing the 'Start' button...
And now I'm screwed up.

Please, fetch me some ideas, will you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, an emulator takes a long time to start up the first time you run it. The way I think of this is that a "system image" has to be built the first time an emulator is run (I don't know whether this is true or not - it's just the way I think of it). On my new laptop, the first time I run an emulator for a tablet device it can easily take 30 mins to start.

The tablet devices are sometimes defined to use more than 700MB of memory which is a problem in Windows. Juno will warn you about this if you look closely at the AVD definition. If you reduce this parameter on the AVD down to 700MB (768MB ?) then it should slowly spring into life.

Finally, I would check the install with a phone emulator first. Good luck !

Comment: Gosh, I reduced the RAM size into 256 from 512MB, and it worked! Thanks that you've reminded me to check the settings!